# When did Yeats enter into "Virgil's territory"?

Tags: william-butler-yeats, virgil

In the definition of "divagate," several dictionaries, like [this one](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/divagate), give the following example sentence:

> Yeats divagated into Virgil's territory only once.

What instance of Yeats' writing does this refer to?

Comment: It's highly possible that one dictionary is copying the example sentences from another one as well, so this may be somewhat tenous a connection.

Comment: Are you looking for the poem in question or the original source for that quote?

Comment: Certainly, Virgil influenced Yeats' poem *Shepherd and Goatherd*, one of at least three poems Yeats wrote in memory of Major Robert Gregory. Yeats himself says "... my poem about Robert, a pastoral, modelled on what Virgil wrote for some friend of his ..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original source of the quote seems to be *Virgil in a Cultural Tradition: Essays to Celebrate the Bimillenium,* edited by 
Richard Andrew Cardwell and Janet Hamilton. [Google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=XpJfAAAAMAAJ&q=yeats+%22Virgil%27s+territory%22&dq=yeats+%22Virgil%27s+territory%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUjvS8u9XfAhVtT98KHRbRDMQQ6AEILjAB) shows that this book contains the quote

> Yeats divagated into Virgil's territory only when, in 1915, he wrote *Per Amica Silentia Lunae*, going for that title to *Aeneid* 2, 255, *A Tenedo tacitae per amica silentia lunae.*

However, referring to the 1918 poem *Shepherd and Goatherd* that he wrote in memory of Major Robert Gregory, Yeats says

> ... my poem about Robert, a pastoral, modelled on what Virgil wrote for some friend of his ..."

So it seems the dictionary quote is wrong, and Yeats divagated into Virgil's territory at least twice.

Comment: *Only when…* can be read as *Not until…* in some contexts (*It was only when [catalyst] that [protagonist] finally took action…*). It needn't insist that it only happened the once, in any case: *Only when it rains am I forced to take cover.*